# Centre contact clamping in coaxial barrel connectors

Tags: connector, low-voltage

Barrel connector plugs seem to have two different methods for keeping the centre contact under pressure.  Some plugs have a rigid circular inner contact which relies on the socket to have a split pin which can press outwards to maintain contact (eg., the non-yellow plugs below).  Others have a pair of clamps within the plug itself, which (I assume) press against a solid pin in the socket (eg., the yellow ones below).

[image: barrel connectors]

I need plugs like those yellow ones, but with solder tags.  When searching, how do I refer to them in a way that distinguishes them from the plugs with a rigid inner contact?

They don't have to be yellow.

Comment: Do you know the OD/ID of the plug? The construction of the plug is dependent on the size. An example would be a "5.5/2.1mm" plug, meaning the outer diameter is 5.5mm and the center pole is 2.1mm.

Comment: I'll need several different sizes, but 5.5/2.1 is one of them.  My biggest concern, though, is to distinguish between the plugs which are able to maintain a good contact on a rigid pin, distinct from those that rely on the pin pressing outwards on the plug.